Java's S3 .listBuckets() call gets back an InvocationTargetException
When I run this code as a jar file (java -jar TestAwsJavaDemoApplication.jar) in my Ubuntu VM (using GCP), I get the bottom exception when GCP's VM hits AWS's S3 Bucket.
It works fine locally! I can see the S3 Buckets List on my Mac Terminal, but not in my VM.
Here's the code.
    package com.maven.cli;
     
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
     
    import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
    import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
    import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
    import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
     
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TestAwsJavaDemoApplication {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestAwsJavaDemoApplication.class, args);
        listBuckets();
    }
       
    private static void listBuckets() {
        System.out.println("Listing buckets");
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();    //InvocationTargetException
        Region unitedStatesRegion = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1);
        s3.setRegion(unitedStatesRegion);
           
        System.out.println("s3= "+ s3);
        for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
          System.out.println(" - " + bucket.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Done Listing the Buckets");
    }     
}

POM.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>

Here's the Tomcat Logs:
Listing buckets
s3= com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client@571c5681
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString(Base64.java:36)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:70)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:58)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3Signer.sign(S3Signer.java:127)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:652)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3697)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3647)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:674)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:682)
        at com.maven.cli.TestAwsJavaDemoApplication.listBuckets(TestAwsJavaDemoApplication.java:55)

